# Custom Type ArrayList with IEnumerator

Tags: c#, generics

See .net fiddle link https://dotnetfiddle.net/E4eCWl

I have a homework assignment to use an ArrayList of type Book so while I know `List<T>` would be the correct way to handle the issue I need to use an ArrayList as that is part of the assignment

so used

```
var books = new ArrayList<Book> {new Book("Moby Dick", 254)};
```

My understanding here is that the once I add the custom type Book to the Arraylist I am creating a custom class as Resharper has helped me create a new class to accommodate the adding of the book, so a new class has been added, but now I am stuck, as I have no idea on how to implement the Add method or what to use the GetEnumerator for..

Any tips or website I can go to to help me further or have I gone down the wrong path to begin with on creating the type.

**Custom Book Class**

```
class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }

    public Book(string title, int pages)
    {
        Title = title;
        NumberOfPages = pages;
    }

}
```

Generated Class

```
class ArrayList<T> : IEnumerable
{
    internal void Add(Book book)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you been told to use the *existing* (non-generic) ArrayList class, or create your own? This sounds like a very odd assignment...

Comment: ArrayList is not a generic class, so you can use it in this way:  var books = new ArrayList { new Book("Moby Dick", 254) };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're meant to be using [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist) which is non-generic - so you'd have:

```
var books = new ArrayList { new Book("Moby Dick", 254) };
```

Of course, using non-generic collections is generally a bad idea, and unless the assignment is specifically making a point about the "somewhat-legacy" collections, I would question the usefulness of it. (Basically, it sounds like this assignment may just be *very* old and in sore need of an update. If you can possibly give feedback about this, do so!)

Comment: Maybe the teacher hasn't yet introduced generics, and prefers to show the old way in order to demonstrate how much the new way is better once the students will know generics.

Comment: @PaoloCosta: *Maybe* - but I'd question the usefulness of it, to be honest.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I think your right on using the non-generic Arraylist but I am sort of curious now on is it possible to use the arraylist in this way or is just confusing the issue ? Obviously It seems to work when I debug the issue I can step through to the add and then the exception is thrown so now its just trying to see if I can get the example to work

Comment: @SimonG: What do you mean by "the exception is thrown"? What exception? If you use *your* code then yes, it'll throw an exception - but I'm suggesting you shouldn't do that... or if you *do* want to implement your own question, that's a fairly different question, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for responding back, the public void Add(Book book){throw new NotImplementedException();} that code was generated by Resharper so that is the exception, so it looks like if I want to try and get the Add method to work I need to implement a custom collection, I suppose I am trying to revive a dead horse but am interested in seeing if I can get it to work

Comment: @SimonG: So what do you want this question to be about - completing the expected assignment, or implementing a collection? They're very different questions, and at the moment *this* question feels like it's more about using the existing `ArrayList` class. Maybe you should try the implementation yourself, and then ask a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Obviously completing the assignment is the priority but this has led me down a path and its a good way I suppose to learn the language as well, that is to try and figure out why C# seems to be ok with allowing me to add a custom type to the arraylist and to see if I can get it to work obviously not for the assignment but for my own education

Comment: @SimonG: Not sure what you mean by "allowing me to add a custom type to the arraylist". Do you mean why `new ArrayList().Add(new Book(...))` works? A non-generic `ArrayList` allows *any* (non-pointer) type to be added, boxing if necessary... Basically it has an `Add(object)` method.

Comment: @JonSkeet OP is very confused....... I've tried to address OP's concerns in my answer with no luck...

Comment: Actually the add part makes sense for now its the defining the new ArrayList <Book> part that has me confused why visual studio allowed me to create it, obviously a whole other discussion here and off topic don't want to take any more of your time

Comment: @SimonG: It allowed you to create it in the same way that if you type `new FooBarBaz` it will offer to create a `FooBarBaz` class for you...

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is a collection from .NET 1.0 and 1.1 days (a long, long time ago *like Star Wars intro...*).

Thus, `ArrayList` was introduced before *generics* and it's not a generic collection.

It differs from `List<T>` in that collection items aren't typed as some concrete type but as `object`. That is, you can add any type of object to the `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(new Pear());
list.Add(new Apple());
```

Also, when you need to get an item, you need to *downcast* to the concrete type again:

```
// list[0] will return the pear typed as System.Object
Pear pear = (Pear)list[0];
```

BTW, as I said in the first paragraph, it's a class that got outdated a long long long long long long (...) time ago and actual code shouldn't use it anymore. You need to use `List<T>` instead (or any other generic list within `System.Collections.Generic` namespace).

Comment: Thanks Matias that makes sense I suppose I am just trying to be stubborn and try figure out how to get C# to actually process the add, what would I need add to the method to get to work

Comment: @SimonG I don't understand what you want to achieve at all... Do you want to implement a collection from scratch, or what?

Comment: Resharper has created a  internal void Add(Book book)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

So yes I guess I do want to implement a collection or a custom implementation I suppose. Thanks

Comment: @SimonG I believe you're very lost... What has to do Resharper with implementing a custom collection? And Visual Studio creates classes and methods for unexisting ones when you write them in code........... (Generate class, Generate method...).

Comment: @SimonG I believe you should either choose Jon Skeet's or my answer as the right one and ask another question (or just search in SO for similar Q&A........)